# Correct format for Select in SQL Server

Tags: mysql, sql-server

I have what should be a simple query for any database and which always runs in MySQL but not in SQL Server

```
select
tagalerts.id,
ts,
assetid,
node.zonename,
battlevel
from tagalerts, node
where
ack=0 and
tagalerts.nodeid=node.id
group by assetid
order by ts desc
```

The error is:

> column tagalerts.id is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the group by clause.

It is not a simple case of adding `tagalerts.id` to the `group by` clause because the error repeats for `ts` and for `assetid` etc, implying that all the selects need to be in a group or in aggregate functions... either of which will result in a meaningless and inaccurate result.

Splitting the select into a subquery to sort and group correctly (which again works fine with MySQL, as you would expect) makes matters worse

```
SELECT * from
(select
tagalerts.id,
ts,
assetid,
node.zonename,
battlevel
from tagalerts, node
where
ack=0 and
tagalerts.nodeid=node.id
order by ts desc 
)T1
group by assetid
```

> the order by clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables and expressions unless TOP etc is used

the 'correct output' should be

```
id     ts                 assetid     zonename     battlevel
1234   a datetime         1569        Reception    0
3182   another datetime   1572        Reception    0
```

Either I am reading SQL Server's rules entirely wrong or this is a major flaw with that database.

How can I write this to work on both systems?

Comment: move the `Order By` to your outer query under the `group by`, but you are still going to get an error from grouping.

Comment: On the contrary, the flaw is in mysql. If you use an aggregate across three columns it only makes sense you need to group by the other columns. If the other columns have more than 1 value which one gets returned if there is no group by?

Comment: What do you want as a result, why are you using group by?

Comment: Thanks, but that results in T1.id is invalid in the select list because it is not contained either in an aggregate function or the group by cluase

Comment: assetid must be grouped otherwise there are multiple rows with the same asset id, precisely what I don't want

Comment: You cant group all the other selects because zonename in many cases is the same and must be shown as separate rows

Comment: You will need to use a window function or rewrite the query. There is no way to force SQL Server to invalidate the group by rules.

Comment: Thanks, I will stay with MySQL for the time being, at least I know the output is always correct with that.

Comment: What MySql allows you to do here actually violates the SQL standard. The Sql Server way (which requires you to use aggregate functions like `MAX()` or `AVG()` with columns that are not in the `group by`) is correct.

Comment: Also, I suspect this query is _**INCORRECT** even in MySql._ We're missing a lot of details (sample data, and we don't know which table all of the columns belong to), but what I do know is you're grouping by `assetid`, where one `assetid` value may have more than one `ts` (timestamp) value in the group. It looks like you're counting on the `order by ts desc` to ensure _both_ that you see recent timestamps in the results first **and** that each `assetid` group uses the most recent `ts` timestamp. MySql only guarantees the former, **not the latter**. You could be seeing the **wrong** timestamps.

Comment: Hmm... gonna promote that to an answer.

Answer (score 2):

In most databases you can't just include columns that aren't in the `GROUP BY` without using an aggregate function.

MySql is an exception to that.  But MS SQL Server isn't.

So you could keep that `GROUP BY` with only the "assetid".
But then use the appropriate aggregate functions for all the other columns.

Also, use the [JOIN](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp) syntax for heaven's pudding sake.
A SQL like `select * from table1, table2 where table1.id2 = table2.id`  is using a syntax from the previous century.

```
SELECT
MAX(node.id) AS id,
MAX(ta.ts) AS ts,
ta.assetid,
MAX(node.zonename) AS zonename,
MAX(ta.battlevel) AS battlevel
FROM tagalerts AS ta
JOIN node ON node.id = ta.nodeid
WHERE ta.ack = 0
GROUP BY ta.assetid
ORDER BY ta.ts DESC;
```

Another trick to use in MS SQL Server is the window function ROW_NUMBER.
But this is probably not what you need.

Example:

```
SELECT id, ts, assetid, zonename, battlevel
FROM
(
  SELECT
   node.id,
   ta.ts,
   ta.assetid,
   node.zonename,
   ta.battlevel,
   ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ta.assetid ORDER BY ta.ts DESC) AS rn
  FROM tagalerts AS ta
  JOIN node ON node.id = ta.nodeid
  WHERE ta.ack = 0
) q
WHERE rn = 1
ORDER BY ts DESC;
```

Comment: Thanks LukStorms I added the max's but it then complained about order by so I deleted the order by and it worked (presumably because of all of the max's). Seems bizarre to me. I will stay away from SQL Server.

Comment: Yeah well, in MS SQL the ORDER BY can only be used in a sub-query if a TOP or FOR XML is used.  But it's really not that bad you know.  That rule with the group by is actually an ANSI SQL standard. And it's MySql that deviates from it, although they explained why they did that somewhere.  Maybe for you the easiest would be to migrate to MySql 8.x or MariaDB.  Some of the cool new SQL stuff like CTE's and window functions are also in those.

Answer (score 1):

I strongly suspect this query is ***WRONG** even in MySql*.

We're missing a lot of details (sample data, and we don't know which table all of the columns belong to), but what I do know is you're grouping by `assetid`, where it looks like one `assetid` value could have more than one `ts` (timestamp) value in the group. It also looks like you're counting on the `order by ts desc` to ensure *both* that you see recent timestamps in the results first **and** that each `assetid` group uses the most recent possible `ts` timestamp for that group.

MySql only guarantees the former, **not the latter.** *Nothing* in this query guarantees that each `assetid` is using the most recent timestamp available. You could be seeing the wrong timestamps, and then also using those wrong timestamps for the `order by`. This is the problem the Sql Server rule is there to stop. **MySql violates the SQL standard** to allow you to write that wrong query.

Instead, you need to look at each column and either add it to the `group by` (best when all of the values are known to be the same, anyway) *or* wrap it in an aggregrate function like `MAX()`, `MIN()`, `AVG()`, etc, so there is a *deterministic* result for which value from the group is used.

If all of the values for a column in a group are the same, then there's no problem adding it to the `group by`. If the values are different, you want to be precise about which one is chosen for the result set.

While I'm here, the `tagalerts, node` join syntax has been obsolete for more than 20 years now. It's also good practice to use an alias with every table and prefix every column with the alias. I mention these to explain why I changed it for my code sample below, though I only prefix columns where I am confident in which table the column belongs to.

This query should run on both databases:

```
SELECT ta.assetid, MAX(ta.id) "id", MAX(ta.ts) "ts",
    MAX(n.zonename) "zonename", MAX(battlevel) "battlevel"
FROM tagalerts ta
INNER JOIN node n ON ta.nodeid = n.id
WHERE ack = 0
GROUP BY ta.assetid
ORDER BY ts DESC
```

There is also a concern here the results may be choosing values from *different records in the joined `node` table.* So if `battlevel` is part of the `node` table, you might see a result that matches a `zonename` with a `battlevel` that never occurs in any record in the data. In Sql Server, this is easily fixed by using `APPLY` to match only one `node` record to each `tagalert`. MySql doesn't support this (APPLY or an equivalent has been in every other major database since at least 2012), but you can simulate with it in this case with *two* JOINs, where the first join is a subquery that uses GROUP BY to determine values will uniquely identify the needed `node` record, and second join is to the `node` table to actually produce that record. Unfortunately, we need to know more about the tables in question to actually write this code for you.